# Julia: How to paste an image from the system clipboard (MS Windows) in a Gtk canvas?

Tags: canvas, julia, clipboard, paste

I want to paste an image from the system clipboard (MS Windows) in a Gtk canvas. As far as I know InteractiveUtils.clipboard only works with text.